# Different order of parameters in strptime and strftime

Tags: python, strftime, strptime

In `time.strftime(format[, t])` the first parameter is `format` and in `time.strptime(string[, format])` it is second parameter. Why is that so? Sometimes i got confused and unintentionally used `format` as first parameter in  `time.strptime` which raised an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general principle is that you put required arguments before optional arguments (and indeed you can't put optional arguments before required arguments only if you were to use keyword arguments, which `time.strftime` and `time.strptime` don't support.) Since `time.strftime(format)` formats the current time, the optional time to use instead of the current time has to be the second argument. And likewise, since `time.strptime(string)` parses `string` according to the default format, the `format` has to be the second argument.